# not able to get the Htmlanchor which got clicked which opened the facebox

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-plugins, facebox

I am tryin to open a facebox and get the id of **HtmlAnchor** which has been clicked to get the facebox. But when I use `server_click` to catch the id of HtmlAnchor clicked `ha.Attributes.Add("rel", "facebox");` is not working.
It looks like `Attributes.Add` and `server_click` are not working properly when used together.
How is it possible to successfully open a facebox and still know the ID of the HtmlAnchor which got clicked.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    var htmlanchor = new HtmlAnchor
    {
        ID = "0" + i,
        HRef = "#info",
        InnerText = "click me"
    };
    htmlanchor .Attributes.Add("rel", "facebox");
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(htmlanchor );
}
```

This is my javascript code

```
/*
* Facebox (for jQuery)
* version: 1.2 (05/05/2008)
* @requires jQuery v1.2 or later
*
* Examples at http://famspam.com/facebox/
*
* Licensed under the MIT:
*   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*
* Copyright 2007, 2008 Chris Wanstrath [ chris@ozmm.org ]
*
* Usage:
*
*  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
*    jQuery('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
*  })
*
*  <a href="#terms" rel="facebox">Terms</a>
*    Loads the #terms div in the box
*
*  <a href="terms.html" rel="facebox">Terms</a>
*    Loads the terms.html page in the box
*
*  <a href="terms.png" rel="facebox">Terms</a>
*    Loads the terms.png image in the box
*
*
*  You can also use it programmatically:
*
*    jQuery.facebox('some html')
*    jQuery.facebox('some html', 'my-groovy-style')
*
*  The above will open a facebox with "some html" as the content.
*
*    jQuery.facebox(function($) {
*      $.get('blah.html', function(data) { $.facebox(data) })
*    })
*
*  The above will show a loading screen before the passed function is called,
*  allowing for a better ajaxy experience.
*
*  The facebox function can also display an ajax page, an image, or the contents of a div:
*
*    jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'remote.html' })
*    jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'remote.html' }, 'my-groovy-style')
*    jQuery.facebox({ image: 'stairs.jpg' })
*    jQuery.facebox({ image: 'stairs.jpg' }, 'my-groovy-style')
*    jQuery.facebox({ div: '#box' })
*    jQuery.facebox({ div: '#box' }, 'my-groovy-style')
*
*  Want to close the facebox?  Trigger the 'close.facebox' document event:
*
*    jQuery(document).trigger('close.facebox')
*
*  Facebox also has a bunch of other hooks:
*
*    loading.facebox
*    beforeReveal.facebox
*    reveal.facebox (aliased as 'afterReveal.facebox')
*    init.facebox
*    afterClose.facebox
*
*  Simply bind a function to any of these hooks:
*
*   $(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() { ...stuff to do after the facebox and contents are revealed... })
*
*/
(function ($) {
    $.facebox = function (data, klass) {
        $.facebox.loading()

        if (data.ajax) fillFaceboxFromAjax(data.ajax, klass)
        else if (data.image) fillFaceboxFromImage(data.image, klass)
        else if (data.div) fillFaceboxFromHref(data.div, klass)
        else if ($.isFunction(data)) data.call($)
        else $.facebox.reveal(data, klass)
    }

    /*
    * Public, $.facebox methods
    */

    $.extend($.facebox, {
        settings: {
            opacity: 0.2,
            overlay: true,
            loadingImage: '/facebox/loading.gif',
            closeImage: '/facebox/closelabel.png',
            imageTypes: ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'],
            faceboxHtml: '\
    <div id="facebox" style="display:none;"> \
      <div class="popup"> \
        <div class="content"> \
        </div> \
        <a href="#" class="close"><img src="/facebox/closelabel.png" title="close" class="close_image" /></a> \
      </div> \
    </div>'
        },

        loading: function () {
            init()
            if ($('#facebox .loading').length == 1) return true
            showOverlay()

            $('#facebox .content').empty()
            $('#facebox .body').children().hide().end().
        append('<div class="loading"><img src="' + $.facebox.settings.loadingImage + '"/></div>')

            $('#facebox').css({
                top: getPageScroll()[1] + (getPageHeight() / 10),
                left: $(window).width() / 2 - 205
            }).show()

            $(document).bind('keydown.facebox', function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 27) $.facebox.close()
                return true
            })
            $(document).trigger('loading.facebox')
        },

        reveal: function (data, klass) {
            $(document).trigger('beforeReveal.facebox')
            if (klass) $('#facebox .content').addClass(klass)
            $('#facebox .content').append(data)
            $('#facebox .loading').remove()
            $('#facebox .body').children().fadeIn('normal')
            $('#facebox').css('left', $(window).width() / 2 - ($('#facebox .popup').width() / 2))
            $(document).trigger('reveal.facebox').trigger('afterReveal.facebox')
        },

        close: function () {
            $(document).trigger('close.facebox')
            return false
        }
    })

    /*
    * Public, $.fn methods
    */

    $.fn.facebox = function (settings) {
        if ($(this).length == 0) return

        init(settings)

        function clickHandler() {
            $.facebox.loading(true)

            // support for rel="facebox.inline_popup" syntax, to add a class
            // also supports deprecated "facebox[.inline_popup]" syntax
            var klass = this.rel.match(/facebox\[?\.(\w+)\]?/)
            if (klass) klass = klass[1]

            fillFaceboxFromHref(this.href, klass)
            return false
        }

        return this.bind('click.facebox', clickHandler)
    }

    /*
    * Private methods
    */

    // called one time to setup facebox on this page
    function init(settings) {
        if ($.facebox.settings.inited) return true
        else $.facebox.settings.inited = true

        $(document).trigger('init.facebox')
        makeCompatible()

        var imageTypes = $.facebox.settings.imageTypes.join('|')
        $.facebox.settings.imageTypesRegexp = new RegExp('\.(' + imageTypes + ')$', 'i')

        if (settings) $.extend($.facebox.settings, settings)
        $('body').append($.facebox.settings.faceboxHtml)

        var preload = [new Image(), new Image()]
        preload[0].src = $.facebox.settings.closeImage
        preload[1].src = $.facebox.settings.loadingImage

        $('#facebox').find('.b:first, .bl').each(function () {
            preload.push(new Image())
            preload.slice(-1).src = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/url\((.+)\)/, '$1')
        })

        $('#facebox .close').click($.facebox.close)
        $('#facebox .close_image').attr('src', $.facebox.settings.closeImage)
    }

    // getPageScroll() by quirksmode.com
    function getPageScroll() {
        var xScroll, yScroll;
        if (self.pageYOffset) {
            yScroll = self.pageYOffset;
            xScroll = self.pageXOffset;
        } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {  // Explorer 6 Strict
            yScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            xScroll = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        } else if (document.body) {// all other Explorers
            yScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
            xScroll = document.body.scrollLeft;
        }
        return new Array(xScroll, yScroll)
    }

    // Adapted from getPageSize() by quirksmode.com
    function getPageHeight() {
        var windowHeight
        if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
            windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
        } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
            windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
            windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        }
        return windowHeight
    }

    // Backwards compatibility
    function makeCompatible() {
        var $s = $.facebox.settings

        $s.loadingImage = $s.loading_image || $s.loadingImage
        $s.closeImage = $s.close_image || $s.closeImage
        $s.imageTypes = $s.image_types || $s.imageTypes
        $s.faceboxHtml = $s.facebox_html || $s.faceboxHtml
    }

    // Figures out what you want to display and displays it
    // formats are:
    //     div: #id
    //   image: blah.extension
    //    ajax: anything else
    function fillFaceboxFromHref(href, klass) {
        // div
        if (href.match(/#/)) {
            var url = window.location.href.split('#')[0]
            var target = href.replace(url, '')
            if (target == '#') return
            $.facebox.reveal($(target).html(), klass)

            // image
        } else if (href.match($.facebox.settings.imageTypesRegexp)) {
            fillFaceboxFromImage(href, klass)
            // ajax
        } else {
            fillFaceboxFromAjax(href, klass)
        }
    }

    function fillFaceboxFromImage(href, klass) {
        var image = new Image()
        image.onload = function () {
            $.facebox.reveal('<div class="image"><img src="' + image.src + '" /></div>', klass)
        }
        image.src = href
    }

    function fillFaceboxFromAjax(href, klass) {
        $.get(href, function (data) { $.facebox.reveal(data, klass) })
    }

    function skipOverlay() {
        return $.facebox.settings.overlay == false || $.facebox.settings.opacity === null
    }

    function showOverlay() {
        if (skipOverlay()) return

        if ($('#facebox_overlay').length == 0)
            $("body").append('<div id="facebox_overlay" class="facebox_hide"></div>')

        $('#facebox_overlay').hide().addClass("facebox_overlayBG")
      .css('opacity', $.facebox.settings.opacity)
      .click(function () { $(document).trigger('close.facebox') })
      .fadeIn(200)
        return false
    }

    function hideOverlay() {
        if (skipOverlay()) return

        $('#facebox_overlay').fadeOut(200, function () {
            $("#facebox_overlay").removeClass("facebox_overlayBG")
            $("#facebox_overlay").addClass("facebox_hide")
            $("#facebox_overlay").remove()
        })

        return false
    }

    /*
    * Bindings
    */

    $(document).bind('close.facebox', function () {
        $(document).unbind('keydown.facebox')
        $('#facebox').fadeOut(function () {
            $('#facebox .content').removeClass().addClass('content')
            $('#facebox .loading').remove()
            $(document).trigger('afterClose.facebox')
        })
        hideOverlay()
    })

})(jQuery);
```

and this is on my aspx page

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript" src="App_Themes/js/Facebox.js" ></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
                        loadingImage: 'images/loading.gif',
                        closeImage: 'images/closelabel.png'
                    })
                })
  </script>



<link href="facebook.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Can you show your javascript where you attempt to read the id of the link?

Comment: That looks like it should be opening the facebox, but I still don't see where you're trying to access the id of the link, or what you need it for.

Comment: i need to insert the id of anchor tag clicked in my database(id of anchor tag will be id of logged in users)

Comment: And yes, it opens the facebox, but i need the id which got clicked, is there any other way other than using anchor tag???

Comment: In that case, I think you would need to attach a click handler, get the id attribute of the link, and use ajax to send it to the server. I don't think you can do a postback, because the page would reload and you'd lose the facebox.

Comment: That's what i was trying to do, i was using server_click to get the id of link but then   htmlanchor .Attributes.Add("rel", "facebox");         does not work properly, it opens a half facebox which has no contents of div "info"

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure you can't do a postback, you need a client-side (javascript) solution. Look into [ajax with jquery here](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/), I think that's what you need.